# How to fix Jinja2 yml indentation

Tags: yaml, jinja2, indentation

I have the below structure of data source in yml format.

```
  systemEmailAccount:
   mode: DEFAULT
   username: test@gmail.com
   password: Test#123
   displayName: "Test"
   senderAddress: test@gmail.com
   oauthClientId: "xxxxxxx"
   oauthSecret: "xxxxxxxxx"
   tokenExpires: 1458168133864
  secondarySystemEmailAccount:
   mode: DEFAULT
   username: test2@gmail.com
   password: Test#123
   displayName: "Test2"
   senderAddress: test2@gmail.com
   oauthClientId: "xxxxxxx"
   oauthSecret: "xxxxxxxxx"
   tokenExpires: 14581681338777
```

I'm trying to regenerate it to a new file using this jinja2 template snippet.

```
     systemEmailAccount:
     {% for key,value in config.systemEmailAccount.items() %}
     {% if key == "mode" or key == "username" or key == "password" or key == "senderAddress" or key == "tokenExpires" %}
     {{ key }}: {{ value }}
     {% else %}
     {{ key }}: {{ '"' }}{{ value }}{{ '"' }}
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     secondarySystemEmailAccount:
     {% for key,value in config.secondarySystemEmailAccount.items() %}
     {% if key == "mode" or key == "username" or key == "password" or key == "senderAddress" or key == "tokenExpires" %}
     {{ key }}: {{ value }}
     {% else %}
     {{ key }}: {{ '"' }}{{ value }}{{ '"' }}
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
```

But the indentation does not seem right in the output.

```
    emailAccount1:
        username: test@gmail.com
            mode: DEFAULT
            password: Test#123
            displayName: "Test"
            senderAddress: test@gmail.com
            oauthClientId: "xxxxxxx"
            oauthSecret: "xxxxxxxxx"
            tokenExpires: 1458168133864
        emailAccount2:
        username: test2@gmail.com
            mode: DEFAULT
            password: Test#123
            displayName: "Test2"
            senderAddress: test2@gmail.com
            oauthClientId: "xxxxxxx"
            oauthSecret: "xxxxxxxxx"
            tokenExpires: 1458168133864
```

Any suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Is the indentation correct in your question? Because I don't see how the template you've shown could result in the indentation in your output.

Comment: @larsks yes i mentioned as it is in the data source

Comment: I ask because using your example data and your template, the output I get doesn't look like the output you show. This leads me to suspect that either (a) there are formatting errors in the question itself, or (b) there is insufficient information here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

have a look at those 2 topics from official `jinja2` docs

- **white space control**: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control
- **filter indent**: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/?highlight=indent#indent

try this snippet below:

```
systemEmailAccount:
{%- for key,value in config.systemEmailAccount.items() %}

  {%- if key == "mode" or key == "username" or key == "password" or key == "senderAddress" or key == "tokenExpires" %}

{%- filter indent(width=2) %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{%- endfilter %}

  {%- else %}

{%- filter indent(width=2) %}
{{ key }}: {{ '"' }}{{ value }}{{ '"' }}
{%- endfilter %}

  {%- endif %}

{%- endfor %}

[..]
```